# "Error occured" in Windows Update 0x80070643

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was casually using my device. I opened Windows Update and saw this:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Update]

This was the error shown to me:

> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x80070643)

I checked the update history and noticed this:

[image: Screenshot of update history]

The two updates were not able to be installed and I guess that is the cause of the error.

How do I fix the Windows Update error?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem with the .Net updates (still unsolved). In my opinion this is a problem with the download server because if I search for the failed updates and download them manually using Edge browser Edge also shows an error after Download but in difference to Windows update Edge allows to ignore this error and start the installer. Unfortunately manually installing the updates had no effect or may be I downloaded the wrong variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried fixing the error by following ***few*** of these steps https://superuser.com/revisions/1685960/4, but I failed.

Finally, I lost hopes and forgot about this issue. I guess I used this approach: [if it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+it+ain%27t+broke%2C+don%27t+fix+it).

After a couple of days, the issue resolved on its own :)

[image: Screenshot of Windows Update]

Answer (score 3):

> How do I fix the Windows Update error?

**First:**

Run the Windows 10 Update Troubleshooter

[Windows 10 update troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-updating-windows-188c2b0f-10a7-d72f-65b8-32d177eb136c)

From an Admin Command Prompt:

> net stop bits
>
> net stop wuauserv
>
> net stop cryptsvc
>
> ren %systemroot%\softwaredistribution softwaredistribution.bak
>
> ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
>
> net start bits
>
> Restart and test updates
>
> Also temporarily remove third party anti virus software
>
> Restart and test updates.

These are the main points. There are more tests including hardware tests in the article.

But start as above and see if the Update function returns

**Next:**

If these steps do not work, it might be best to run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to keep everything.

Comment: I ran `ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak` and got `Access is denied.`

Comment: I did run from an admin command prompt.

Comment: You need to be sure you used an Admin Command Prompt. I assume you did. The next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything. I added this to my post

Comment: Also click on the article and review all the steps to be sure you got them all.

Comment: Are you just repeating standard kitchen sink advice here, or do you have some evidence that this will help?

Comment: They did not help in my case, which is just a couple of .NET updates stuck with this error code. I think running a Windows repair install just to fix a couple of stuck windows updates in an otherwise functional system is kind of crazy.

Comment: Didn't help for me, but this script did https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-windows-update-in-windows-11.3808/